# AIX nfs mount-point disappears (not seen even from parent dir) until umount/mount

Tags: ls, nfs, aix

I have experienced my share of NFS "hangouts" and related things. But today I saw something different, and I am puzzled: the mount-dir itself is not visible (/foo, not visible from / ) until I unmounted/mounted again "/foo" (a NFS share). This is on AIX 6.1

```
## grep -p '^/foo' /etc/filesystems
/foo:
        dev             = "/foo_for_client"
        vfs             = nfs
        nodename        = fooserver
        mount           = true
        options         = rw,bg,hard,intr,sec=sys
        account         = false

#df
 (...)
fooserver:/foo_for_client          -         -    -         -     -  /foo
 # shows that "fooserver:foo_for_client" is mounted on /foo mount-point
 # BUT each field instead of showing size, %, etc, shows "-" instead
 (...)

## cd /
## ls -ld /foo
ls: 0653-341 The file /foo does not exist.
  # ??    
## ls -l /
  (...)
fmm
fnn   
  #and here, NO 'foo' at all. No mount-point (nor mounted) . 
  #And there is also no "stalling" of the display while it fetches '/foo' infos
  # (ie, the rest of the '/' dir content appears quickly)
  # ??? this '/foo' mount-dir seems to be somehow "hidden" (NFS pb?) (see it reappear below)
fpp
fqq
  (...)

## umount /foo
 # no errors.

## cd /
## ls -ld /foo
drwxrwxrwx    2 user    user             256 Jan 01 1970  /foo
 # ?? the mount-point is there and does exist? (even though its date is suspicious)
 # why was it 'hidden' from '/' standpoint while the nfs was mounted?

## mount /foo
 # no errors, and everything is ok again...

#df
 (...)
fooserver:/foo_for_client  220200960  69811632 69%   1122    1% /foo
 # Now each field appears as well
 (...)
```

I understand that the "/foo/." dir superseeds "/foo" mount-dir once the nfs filesystem is mounted. 
And that when the NFS goes wrong, it can then make that "inside" content be unavailable.

But what I can't understant is how this "/foo" couldn't be seen from the parent directory as well?
 (from "/", it should know there is a "/foo" subdir entry, and then show it via ls (with the NFS infos when NFS is mounted or the "/" partition info when it isn'). Here: I couldn't see "/foo" at all (nor the mount-dir, nor the mounted one).

I guess this somehow comes from NFS failing to return infos when "ls" queries infos about "/foo" directory? but in that case why does "ls -l" from "/" fails silently, and without any timeouts on that subdir? (And I forgot to "truss"-ed my ls -l attempt...)

Comment: I don't suppose you happened to re-mount the root filesystem? A copy of it that didn't have a `/foo` directory?

Comment: @JeffSchaller: nothing (that I know of) happened on the / filesystem, no. Seems at some point the NFS went weird (but without the tell-tale hangouts on it on df output or when trying to ls its mount-point), and this weird "hiding" happened.

Comment: note that "df" now shows infos of the "/foo" mount point (sizes, etc), instead of "-" for each fields.

Comment: were you, as hinted at with the `#` prompts, root the whole time?

Comment: @JeffSchaller, yes I was root the whole time. got called by a user who couldn't get into /foo.

Comment: I can reproduce the `df`  `- - - ` output if one of the parent directories of the mount point doesn't have read permission for the current user -- thus my 'root' question.

Comment: @JeffSchaller: well, here I was root. To me it's simply that NFS doesn't answer (... instantly?) and it is just a side effect (even though it may help finding the context of the real pb: that "/foo" mount-point itself disappearing (as if it disappeared from  "/." entry as well?) when the NFS mount was not completely ok)

Comment: Your comment about df output `each field instead of showing size, %, etc, shows "-" instead` suggests that this was maybe an issue with the NFS server - this often happens when e.g. the NFS server did unexport and re-export the NFS filesystem while you had it mounted, it will usually be OK again on the client if you unmount and mount it again (re-mount will usually not work in such cases).

Can you check what happened on the NFS server during the time you observed this on the client? Unless the server is also AIX, because then there isn't much logging happening by default ...